android keyboard （GoogleLatinIME）How to hide the emoji button entry in the keyboard,Don't let the user click
enter image description here
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this,such as image
android keyboard （GoogleLatinIME）How to hide the emoji button entry in the keyboard,Don't let the user click
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this,such as image
android keyboard （GoogleLatinIME）How to hide the emoji button entry in the keyboard,Don't let the user click

Are you writing a keyboard or an application that uses keyboard? If the latter, you have no control over what keyboard the user choose and what the choosen keyboard can be capable of. So your only option is to filter the user input and remove emoji values before you use (send/process/etc) the user's text.
